# delete selected row from table

Tags: php, html

i need to delete / edit selected row from table with checkbox
i am showing a table from my database

this is the table

```
<table width="100%" class="table-responsive" style="border: solid;border-color: white;">
<tr style="background: #737375;color: white;">
<td></td>
<td align="center" style="border: solid;border-color: white;">Accomodation</td>
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;" align="center">Address</td><br>
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;" align="center">Rooms</td>
<td align="center" style="border: solid;border-color: white;">Status</td>
<td align="center" style="border: solid;border-color: white;">Delete</td>
<td align="center" style="border: solid;border-color: white;">Edit</td>
</tr>
```

filling the table

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","","");
$link=mysql_select_db("orangeom_orangedb");
$req="select * from accomodation order by accid";
$res=mysql_query($req);
$i=1;
while ($ligne1=mysql_fetch_object($res))
{ $i=$i+1;
?>
<tr <?php if( bcmod($i, 2)==0) {echo "bgcolor='#FFCC99'"; } ?> >
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><div class="radio" align="center">
<label><input type="radio" name="radio[]" id="radio[]" value="<?php echo $ligne1->accid;?>"></label>
</div></td> 
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><input name="uid" type="hidden" id="uid" value="<?php echo $ligne1->accid;?>"/><?php echo $ligne1->name;?></td>
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><?php echo $ligne1->address;?></td>
<td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><?php echo $ligne1->rooms;?></td>
<?php
    if($ligne1->status =='1')
    {?>
    <td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><div align="center"><img src="../../images/Active.png"  width="16px" height="16px"/></div></td>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {?>
    <td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><div align="center"><img src="../../images/NotActive.png"  width="16px" height="16px"/></div></td>
    <?php
    }?>
    <td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><div align="center"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete ???');" href='delAccomodation.php?accid=<?php echo $ligne1->tripID; ?>&accid=<?php echo $ligne1->accid; ?>'><img src='../../images/Delete.png' width='16' height='16'/></a></div></td>
    <td style="border: solid;border-color: white;"><div align="center"><a href='interAccomodation.php?accid=<?php echo $ligne1->accid; ?>&accname=<?php echo $ligne1->name;?>&accaddress=<?php echo $ligne1->address; ?>&accrooms=<?php echo $ligne1->rooms; ?>&accstat=<?php echo $ligne1->status;?>'><img src='../../images/Edit.png' width='16' height='16' /></a></div></td>
</tr>
<?php }
mysql_close();?>
</table>
```

i want select one row and delete by an image

```
<img src="../../images/delete.png" id="delete" width="16px" height="16px"/>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You might also want to change that password now.

Comment: So basically you are asking us to write the PHP code to do the delete. Right?

Comment: i have the delete code for each row
but i want to do it outside the table

Comment: Well you already have the anchor tag in place to do the delete, so I dont understand what you are asking

Comment: i want to remove the delete and edit buttons from each row
i will delete using a button outside the table when the checkbox is checked

Comment: well you need to start by adding some checkboxes to the HTML with the item IDs as values. Then on the server, when the delete button is pressed, loop through all the post variables and find the ones that are present (unchecked checkboxes are not even sent in the POST variables). Then use those values to include in your delete query.